# How to reset the user/password of Jenkins on Windows?

Tags: windows, jenkins

Maybe a fool question, I installed jenkins on windows by default, have set no user/password, it worked at first, no need to login. But when launch the 8080 webpage now, it hangs the login page, I've tried some normal user/password combinations, none could pass. Also searched the resolution on website, only find some about linux, no about windows, so need help.
[jenkins login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1MUM.png)

Comment: It is getting changed from version to version.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can try to re-set your Jenkins security:

1. Stop the Jenkins service
2. Open the `config.xml` with a text editor (i.e notepad++), maybe be in `C:\jenkins\config.xml` (could backup it also).
3. Find this `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` and change it to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`
4. Start Jenkins service

You might create an admin user and enable security again.

Note:  On more recent Jenkins versions running on Windows the config.xml file is found here:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\

Comment: Search for the config.xml in all disks, but none is found.

Comment: It worked when I deployed a new jenkins setup.
The **config.xml** default path is under
 **C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins**.

Comment: @Mardok, Jenkins 2. is a new Jenkins branch. You might need to add more details.

Comment: @Tuan I found answer in some other threads. The password was in 'secrets' folder. Thanks!

Comment: For me, the correct file is C:\Users\User_Name\.jenkins\config.xml not C:\Program Files\Jenkins\config.xml

Comment: @dante Thanks. The ```config.xml``` will be put in your ```JENKINS_HOME```. If you don't set it, the file will be put in ```%USERPROFILE%\.jenkins\```

Comment: access denied to file config.xml

Comment: @AmaanMemon, you have to turn off Jenkins service. And please make sure you have Admin right when opening the config.xml

Comment: It worked when I deployed a new jenkins setup but after login blank browser window oped?

Comment: @RahulDapke, please do not login. Before that, you can use Jenkins as an anonymous without logging in. Then you can go to http://JENKIND_URL:8080/configureSecurity and enable the Security option.

Comment: On Ubuntu Linux, where do you find the config.xml file?

Comment: @tarekahf it's the ```$JENKINS_HOME```. Maybe ```/var/lib/jenkins/``` by default.

Comment: Could not found "<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>"  inside config file

Comment: @TaritRay Can you search for ```useSecurity``` only? If you can't find it, that means you don't enable Jenkins security.

Comment: found my config.xml in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins but visiting port 8080 immediately sets it to true again and responds with just "P"

Comment: @Heras, have you fixed your issue?

Comment: @Tuan, sadly not. The time I spent trying to get Jenkins to properly work made me afraid of maintenance, so I moved away.

Comment: Make sure you should install Java 8 or 11 in windows 10 so it will work properly.

Comment: If you have been removed initialAdminPassword file it will get error. you should create an empty file with initialAdminPassword name before using this approuch.

Comment: You can check the JENKINS_HOME path in ```jenkins.xml``` [ path to file : ```C:\Program Files\Jenkins```]. Mine was ```<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins"/>```

Answer (score 17):

Read Initial password :

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

Default username is **'admin'** and the password is the one from initialAdminPassword when you follow the above path.

```
'Manage Jenkins' --> 'Manage Users' --> Password
```

Then logout and login to make sure new password works.

Answer (score 9):

This is for windows environment:

I got the Initial Admin password under 
C:\Users\Deepak("MyUser").jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

I was able to login with user "admin" and  above password.
Then under Jenkins> people
I edited the password of the user and clicked on apply to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, jenkin version 2.291 you find the password in secret.key in the path ***C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins***. Attached the screenshot please have a look .

[image: INITIAL ADMIN PASSWORD PATH FOR JENKIN ON WINDOWS]

But my observation is the path is getting changed from version to version. So if You are using **different version of JENKINS** then please check other paths

***1 -> C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword***

***2 -> C:\Users\LOGGED USER.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword***

Comment: Thanks. After installing Jenkins 2.361.1 on Windows Server 2022 I found the initial admin password is in C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets. (This being the location of JENKINS_HOME in jenkins.xml). But tomorrow, could be somewhere else!

Answer (score 2):

I created a new user with "admin" and new password on the installation steps. But after sometime, i wanted to sign in again and that password was showing incorrect, so i used the initial password again to login.

The initial password can be found in the below location:-

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

try this method

Answer (score 2):

- First, you need to find the Jenkins `config.xml`. The file location
  could be different based on the Jenkins version. Go to `C:\Program Files\Jenkins(depends on where Jenkins is installed)`and find
  `jenkins.xml`. Look for `<env name=”JENKINS_HOME” value=”%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins”/>`. Copy the value and paste
  it into the Windows run, you will be taken to the respective path.
- Next, stop the Jenkins service in the Windows service. Afterward,
  look for `config.xml` in `.jenkins` folder then change
  `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to
  `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`. Back to windows service to start
  the Jenkins service and access Jenkins URL. You can access Jenkins
  without entering the credentials.

**If You want to set password again then follow these below steps**

Navigate to Manage `Jenkins -> Configure Global Security` and follow setup as below. After hitting Save, you will be taken to create first admin user. Fill up all details then save it. You can use the created credentials to login to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, no possible connection at second login.

After solving the problem (useSecurity, etc., see above), I realized that **admin/admin** worked (with Synology, if that's relevant).

Answer (score 1):

1 ) Copy the initialAdminPassword in Specified path.

2 ) Login with following Credentials

```
User Name : admin

Password : <da12906084fd405090a9fabfd66342f0>
```

[image]

3 ) Once you login into the jenkins application you can click on admin profile and reset the password.

[image]

Comment: This is useful incase user didnt reset the original password

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 after I installed Jenkins on my windows machine the default directory doesn't contain the initial password. (in the first login they give the path). I faced the same issue that mentioned but luckily password on the windows clipboard(Windows logo key+V). The recommendation from me is when your first login changes your user name and password and note down.

Answer (score 1):

1-go to C:\Users\[name]\.jenkins in my my case the name of device is Admin
[image]

2-open config.xml

[image]

3- disable authentification by changing `<useSecurity>` from true to false

4- restart jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot your username then you can simply goto the path **`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\`** and find USER folder. Here you will get config.xml file that file is having username.

After that If you want to disable user authentication, then set it to

Find this in config.xml -> `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity> and change it to <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`

Answer (score 0):

Well as for new Jenkins versions (and win 11) if you are unable to find the config.xml than go to: "C:**ProgramData**\Jenkins.jenkins".

to reset the password / add signup feature etc':

1. Stop jenkins service.
2. go to the config.xml file and change to: false
3. start the service
4. Open the Jenkins url (localhost:8080 for example)
5. Go to security configuration (http://localhost:8080/manage/configureSecurity/) and change to:
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the initial password in the path 
***C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword***

Then I login successfully with "administrator" as an user name.

Comment: This does not reset the password (which is what has been asked for).

Comment: I'd think it is a solution that you can manage the user(disable the security or edit/add another admin user) after login with the initial admin user.

Comment: Inappropriate response