# Jenkins Pipeline localhost:7080

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I ran Jenkins on `localhost:9080` and implemented certain tests.

The next step was to create jenkins pipeline on the `port 7080` from terminal which worked the first time.

Unfortunately i **didn't save the password** and every reset after that doesn't give me the new one.

I restarted this project from scratch at least 4 times and jenkins and password has ever been provided.

Is there a way to make it spit out the new admin password for me?

Comment: I don't think so. See [How to reset the user/password of Jenkins on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39340322/1744774).

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with the localhost or Jenkins itself but with Docker that was pulling it from the memory. Deleting the image or resetting Docker solved the issue.