# How to reset my jenkins user id and password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

Forgot my Jenkins User ID and password is there any way to uninstall and remove the backup completely so that I can reinstall Jenkins with new settings/configurations? I tried finding the config file so that I could altered the

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

but I couldn't find the config file.

I also tried removing the application including the cache but yet installing again it shows me the login window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fGSC.png)

Comment: The `config.xml` is present in **/var/lib/jenkins/** directory in Linux machines. or If windows, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340322/how-to-reset-the-user-password-of-jenkins-on-windows

Comment: Hey I tried following the same, but unfortunately I am not able to find my config file at the location mentioned...