# Change Jenkins service user credentials and restart Jenkins with all existing configurations

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have one tool that is using Jenkins builds.
Jenkins was installed based on a system user Ex.ABC123, jobs were configured , and we had some 3 jobs which was given Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy and only restricted users was having the access.

But unfortunately we had to change the password of this system user ABC123 and now the Jenkins is no more accessible.

I had searched for some solutions , but really didnt get what is required.

Got some workaround from this [Change the security setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340322/how-to-reset-the-user-password-of-jenkins-on-windows). With this the security was removed , so the Jenkins was accessible to everyone, which needs to be restricted again like before based on the groups

I tried to add the groups again , but getting [Group not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBEYg.png)

Can anyone help in this to resolve and make the Jenkins working as before